# What are the advantages of password "leasing"

Tags: passwords, password-management, secrets-management, hashicorp-vault

One the Hashicorp Vault basic feature is *secret leasing*. They state:

> Leasing and Renewal: All secrets in Vault have a lease associated with them. At the end of the lease, Vault will automatically revoke that secret. Clients are able to renew leases via built-in renew APIs.

At the top of my head, I compare such feature with TLS Forward Secrecy: even if the attacker had recorded past traffic and gain access to the main secret, confidentiality remains intact, because each session use a temporary secret.

However, in vault case, the protection is reversed. It protects against service password leaks, not the client password leak. Vault gives temporary service secrets to clients, revoking these service secrets once the sessions are considered over. Thus, even if a temporary secret is compromised, it cannot be used.

Is it the only purpose of this feature? Is there something I'm missing?

I would like to list all the advantages - and perhaps, drawbacks - of that feature, so I can explain it better to my colleagues and other managers.

Many thanks.

---

EDIT reflexion 1

One of the advantages of temporary secret is that, in case of leakage, attacker have a very small window of attack. However, because Vault is a distant secure key/value store, scripts and end users will fetch their secrets dynamically, *by design*. Then, because secrets are rarely (never?) stored cleartext on clients, I don't see how temporary secrets makes sense, because they are unlikely to leak.

As an attacker, I would focus entirely on the authentication mecanism to Vault itself, rather than trying to grab a single password in a flat file or in memory.

Comment: If I understand this correctly this is similar to JWT refresh tokens. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I would say it’s similar to JWT tokens (without the refresh)? In a sense that each session would have its own temporary secret VS static secret.